# How to fix corrupted Windows notification area

Tags: windows-8.1, notification-area

The notification area on my computer is not working properly. *Sound Service*, *Windows Network*, and *Windows Security Center* all open their respective Troubleshooters, which fail to find any problems.

So currently I cannot play sound or access the internet on my computer.

Here are the main problems:

1. The Audio Service fails to start and opens in troubleshooting.
2. The Windows Security Center service (in the Action Center) fails to start and a notification pops up stating "Windows Security Center Service cannot be started."
3. The Windows Network fails to search for connections and the Troubleshooter fails to find any problems.

I've tried a System Restore, which does not show any restore points. I've tried `sfc /scannow` in an elevated CMD Prompt and get an error message:

`Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service.`

When I open Windows I get a ClientCore.exe error. I've been trying to fix it for hours and I just can't figure out what's wrong with it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is a picture of my messed up Notifications Area: 
[image: 1]

Comment: I can't answer the question directly, but can give an advise. It look like severe registry corruption, so, if you don't have restore points or backups, fastest way is to recover is reinstall. Fortunately, Win 8.1 have an easy way to do it: `Win`+`C` → Settings → Change PC Settings (at lower boundary) → Update and Recovery → Recovery. There you'll have your options.

Comment: When I go to Recovery a error comes up: 'There was a problem refreshing your PC'

Comment: then you messed up your system really badly. Reinstall with bootable disk / flash. Note that if you've got an OEM Windows, you'll need to use corresponding install media, otherwise you won't be able to activate it with your key.

Comment: if you use a 64 windows, open a 64Bit CMD.exe. Also make sure that the "Windows Module Installer" service is running.

Comment: Go to Notification Area Properties their you'll notice an option to customize how explorer handles previous tray icons. The only problem with this is explorer saves a setting for EVERY icon ever loaded.

For some reason if you clear this history of icons the power, network, volume...icons will all reappear.

Comment: @LogicDaemon What do I Reinstall? I have a HP Laptop, so I'm pretty sure it's OEM.

Comment: @vembutech: Clearing the notification area icon history (which BTW is not permanent) won't fix the corruption in this case.

Comment: @HELPMEPLZ: Try running `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` from an elevated i.e. admin command prompt.

Comment: I typed in that command in a elevated cmd prompt and I got this error message: `Error: 87 The cleanup-image option is unknown. For more information, refer to the help by running DISM.exe /?.`

Comment: @HELPMEPLZ There are high chances you've got recovery alive, then reset your notebook to factory defaults. Basically, this is manufacturer-provided reinstall on separate HDD partition. Recovery is accessible via [F11 shortly after powering on](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/HP-2000-windows-8-1-help-cannot-factory-reset/td-p/4629854). If there's no such partition for any reason, or it's damaged altogether, you need to buy recovery disks (contact HP service) or get them by other means (download from a *cough*rate site).

Comment: It looks like Windows will let me "Refresh" my PC. If I do so, will I lose any of my files or computer data?

Comment: It worked! I lost all my programs which I will have to reinstall. But at least it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Press the Windows key, type regedit, and press Enter to open the Registry Editor.
Navigate to and select HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify.
Delete both IconStreams and PastIconStream in the right pane.
Press Ctrl-Alt-Delete and select Start Task Manager.
Select the Processes tab, choose explorer.exe, and click End Process.
Choose the Applications tab, click New Task, enter explorer.exe in the text box, and press Enter.

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting. Otherwise, please verify your proof supporting what you state.